# Emulate std::function functionality

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I'm trying to emulate the `std::function` functionality below, but I'm running into the following error

```cpp
class Player
{
public:
void move_to(Point location);
};
std::function<void(Player&, Point)> fun = &Player::move_to;
Player hero;
fun(hero, point{ 2, 4 });
```

```cpp
fp.cc:32:33: error: variable ‘fun<void(Player&, Point)> f’ has initializer but incomplete type
   32 |    fun<void(Player &, Point p)> f = &Player::move_to;
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct fun;

template <typename Ret, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct fun <Ret(*)(T&, Args...)>{
   char *data;
   using fptr = Ret(T::*)(Args...);
   fun(fptr p) : data(p) {}
   Ret operator()(T &t, Args... args) {
      if (std::is_same_v<Ret, void>) {
         (t.*((fptr)data))(args...);
      }
      return (t.*((fptr)data))(args...); 
   }
};

struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
};

struct Player {
   void move_to(Point p) {
      cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   fun<void(Player &, Point p)> f = &Player::move_to;
   Point p{1,2};
   Player pl;
//   f(pl, p);
}
```

Comment: "function" and "pointer-to-function" are different types, you are trying to instantiate `fun` with the former but only have a specialisation for the latter.

Comment: No need for the special case: `std::is_same_v<Ret, void>`: returning `void` expression is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct unused_t {};
// can store any of a function pointer, member function pointer, or other
// pointer.  It is a bit annoying, and not complete even.
union state_t {
  void(unused_t::*pm)();
  void(*pf)();
  void*pv;
  state_t():pv(nullptr){}
  template<class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(*f)(A0s...)):pf(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(f)) {}
  template<class X, class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(X::*f)(A0s...)):pm(reinterpret_cast<void(unused_t::*)()>(f)) {}
  template<class X, class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(X::*f)(A0s...) const):pm(reinterpret_cast<void(unused_t::*)()>(f)) {}
  // add in & and && overloads of member function pointers here

  template<class T>
  state_t(T* p):pv((void*)p) {}
};
template<class Sig>
struct fun;

template <class R, class...As>
struct fun <R(As...)>{
  using pf_t = R(*)(state_t, As&&...);

  state_t state;
  pf_t pf = nullptr;

  fun() = default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return pf; }
  template<class R0, class...A0s>
  fun( R0(*f)(A0s...) ):
    state(f),
    pf([](state_t state, As&&...as)->R{
      auto f = (R0(*)(A0s...))(state.pf);
      return std::invoke( f, std::forward<As>(as)... );
    })
  {}
  template<class T, class R0, class...A0s>
  fun( R0(T::*f)(A0s...) ):
    state(f),
    pf([](state_t state, As&&...as)->R{
      auto f = (R0(T::*)(A0s...))(state.pm);
      return std::invoke( f, std::forward<As>(as)... );
    })
  {}
  template<class T, class R0, class...A0s>
  fun( R0(T::*f)(A0s...) const ):
    state(f),
    pf([](state_t state, As&&...as)->R{
      auto f = (R0(T::*)(A0s...) const)(state.pm);
      return std::invoke( f, std::forward<As>(as)... );
    })
  {}
  R operator()(As... args) const {
    return pf( state, std::forward<As>(args)... );
  }
};
```

this does use `std::invoke`.

Test code:

```
struct bob {
  int foo() const { return 3; };
};
int main() {
  fun<int(bob&)> f = &bob::foo;
  bob b;
  std::cout << f(b);
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/9P5h1TzYh).

Here is a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) version:

```
struct unused_t {};
// can store any of a function pointer, member function pointer, or other
// pointer.  It is a bit annoying, and not complete even.
union state_t {
  void(unused_t::*pm)();
  void(*pf)();
  void*pv;
  state_t():pv(nullptr){}
  template<class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(*f)(A0s...)):pf(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(f)) {}
  template<class X, class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(X::*f)(A0s...)):pm(reinterpret_cast<void(unused_t::*)()>(f)) {}
  template<class X, class R0, class...A0s>
  state_t(R0(X::*f)(A0s...) const):pm(reinterpret_cast<void(unused_t::*)()>(f)) {}
  // add in & and && overloads of member function pointers here

  template<class T>struct tag_t {};
  template<class T>using type_t = T;

  template<class R, class...As>
  type_t<R(*)(As...)> extract( tag_t<R(*)(As...)>) const {
    return (R(*)(As...))pf;
  }
  template<class T, class R, class...As>
  type_t<R(T::*)(As...)> extract( tag_t<R(T::*)(As...)>) const {
    return (R(T::*)(As...))pm;
  }
  template<class T, class R, class...As>
  type_t<R(T::*)(As...) const> extract( tag_t<R(T::*)(As...) const>) const {
    return (R(T::*)(As...) const)pm;
  }
  template<class T>
  type_t<T*> extract( tag_t<T*>) const {
    return (T*)pv;
  }
  template<class T>
  state_t(T* p):pv((void*)p) {}
};
template<class Sig>
struct fun;

template <class R, class...As>
struct fun <R(As...)>{
  using pf_t = R(*)(state_t, As&&...);

  state_t state;
  pf_t pf = nullptr;

  fun() = default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return pf; }
  template<std::invocable<As...> F>
  requires std::is_convertible_v< std::invoke_result_t<F, As...>, R >
  fun( F f ):
    state(std::forward<F>(f)),
    pf([](state_t state, As&&...as)->R{
      auto f = state.extract(state_t::tag_t<F>{});
      return std::invoke( f, std::forward<As>(as)... );
    })
  {}
  R operator()(As... args) const {
    return pf( state, std::forward<As>(args)... );
  }
};
```

the annoying part is the storage of a pointer to member function, pointer or function pointer in a uniform way.  The C++ standard states that those 3 types of pointers are not guaranteed compatible.

So the `state_t` type can store any one of the 3 in a union, but there is a bunch of boilerplate to treat them uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close but has a couple small errors:

- You have only provided a definition of `fun` for `Ret(*)(T&, Args...)`, but `fun<void(Player &, Point p)>` does not match this template. So I removed the `(*)` which is not really required in your specialization.
- A function pointer is not convertible to/from `char *`, so I changed the type of `data` to be `fptr` so it matches the argument type.

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+fun%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Ret,+typename+T,+typename+...Args%3E%0Astruct+fun+%3CRet(T%26,+Args...)%3E%7B%0A+++using+fptr+%3D+Ret(T::*)(Args...)%3B%0A+++fptr+data%3B%0A+++fun(fptr+p)+:+data(p)+%7B%7D%0A+++Ret+operator()(T+%26t,+Args...+args)+%7B%0A++++++if+(std::is_same_v%3CRet,+void%3E)+%7B%0A+++++++++(t.*((fptr)data))(args...)%3B%0A++++++%7D%0A++++++return+(t.*((fptr)data))(args...)%3B+%0A+++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Point+%7B%0A+++int+x%3B%0A+++int+y%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Player+%7B%0A+++void+move_to(Point+p)+%7B%0A++++++cout+%3C%3C+__PRETTY_FUNCTION__+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A+++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A+++fun%3Cvoid(Player+%26,+Point+p)%3E+f+%3D+%26Player::move_to%3B%0A+++Point+p%7B1,2%7D%3B%0A+++Player+pl%3B%0A+++f(pl,+p)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct fun;

template <typename Ret, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct fun <Ret(T&, Args...)>{
   using fptr = Ret(T::*)(Args...);
   fptr data;
   fun(fptr p) : data(p) {}
   Ret operator()(T &t, Args... args) {
      if (std::is_same_v<Ret, void>) {
         (t.*((fptr)data))(args...);
      }
      return (t.*((fptr)data))(args...); 
   }
};

struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
};

struct Player {
   void move_to(Point p) {
      cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   fun<void(Player &, Point p)> f = &Player::move_to;
   Point p{1,2};
   Player pl;
   f(pl, p);
}
```

Comment: W.r.t. (2) above, does that apply specifically to member function pointers?

Comment: This isn't quite a std function.  It is a bit weaker.  The function/data split lets you take more than just a member function as your constructor argument.  `union { void* pv; void(*pf)(); void(X::*pm)(); } data; T(*pf)(data, Args...);`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Would you be able to edit the answer above or provide an alternate answer. I'm assuming ```X``` above is ```T```. By ```T(*pf)```, where is the reference input to ```operator(...)``` being used ?